# I bought a second hand iphone 3gs, but its locke to at&t can it be used in the uk any help would be great

Tags: itunes

I bought a second hand iphone 3gs, and after 3 days of trying to connect it I relised it was with at&t network, done a imei check and it says out of contract and active, which I don't quite understand (supose being welsh does that) I would love to use the phone so any help would be great, I could have it unlocked for 20.00 but they said I would only be able to text and talk, I can't get past the emergencency screen. Imei check says that the contract has expired, iphone is activated, sim locked,

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as the other is for a US phone now in the UK and so answer might well differ here

Answer (score 0):

You most probably can:). But that depends on many factors.

One way is talk to att&t and ask them to unlock, there is even a [Page](https://www.att.com/deviceunlock/client/en_US/termsAndCondition) for that.(for free if contract period is off).

Other is to pay some third party websites, which will unlock it for for you.

Third will be to unlock it using something like ultra snow after jail-breaking. Visit some Good jail-breaking sites for that.